# How to add an activity to more than 1000 non-follower user feeds?

Tags: ruby, getstream-io

I am trying to add an activity to many user feeds which aren't following the activity actor. I was thinking about using the "to" field, but GetStream [only allows to target up to 100 feeds](http://getstream.io/docs/#targetting).

In my application I have a "promotion" activity which should be seen on every user feed, but sometimes we also want to target a "promotion" to a specific group of users, filtered by a property on them.

A promotion has a user as an actor, but the promotion should still appear on another user's feed even if that user doesn't follow the actor.

Sometimes I want to send out a promotion to 80k users.

How could I solve this?

I am using the Ruby library, and the Rails integration.

Comment: 'Note: The "TO" field is limited to a maximum of 100 targets per API request'. Can you just make 10 API requests?

Comment: @NilsLandt I need to do more than 100. Actually more than 1000.

Comment: Yeah, make API request 1 for feeds 1-100, API request 2 for feeds 101-200, etc.

Comment: @NilsLandt won't that create an activity on the user feed for each 100 users?

Comment: if I could suppress the creation of the activity on the user feed each time, then that would be the perfect solution.

Comment: @KennyMeyer could you add a bit of context about the app? what are the criteria used to generate the list of target feeds?

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli I've added more details to the body - let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly pointed out the `to` target is not suited for your use case. The amount of targets you can include in a request is limited to 100. Luckily Stream's API expose [a batch operation](https://getstream.io/docs/#batch-activity-add) to add the same activity to many feeds.

This is an advanced functionality which you can use from the API client, since you are using the Rails integration, you can do something like this:

```
client = StreamRails.client
activity = self.create_activity
client.add_to_many(activity, ["flat:1", "flat:2", "flat:3"])
```

Note that `self` in the code example is the instance of your activity model.

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of feeds you can target with the `add_to_many` API call? Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Also, will there be a new activity added to the actor's user feed for each call with `add_to_many`? The preferable situation would be to only show the activity on the target feed, and not create on the actor's user feed.

Comment: @KennyMeyer in this case you might want to switch off the auto sync off for you model and to the add_many manually. the version of the rails gem on master branch allow you to do that (a release will follow in the coming days)  https://github.com/getstream/stream-rails#activity-creation